# react-native-device-info not working to get Unique id

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get the unique device id. Not able to fetch it. Below attached is the code used.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";

var DeviceInfo = 0; //  require("react-native-device-info");
import { getUniqueId, getManufacturer } from "react-native-device-info";
//import DeviceInfo from "react-native-device-info";

export default class Myproject extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      DeviceID: " ",
    };
  }

  getDeviceID = () => {
    var id = getUniqueId; //DeviceInfo.getBatteryLevel();

    this.setState({
      DeviceID: id,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", fontSize: 20, marginBottom: 10 }}>
          {this.state.DeviceID}
        </Text>

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.getDeviceID}
          activeOpacity={0.5}
          style={styles.button}
        >
          <Text >
            {" "}
            CLICK HERE TO GET DEVICE UNIQUE ID{" "}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Error picture is attached... React Native version is 0.61.5

Comment: error picture is not attached -- instead, can you post the error text you're getting?

Comment: the error is react-native-community/react-native-device-info:NativeModules.RNDeviceInfo is null